# Creating a stopwatch in angular with ng2-simple-timer

Tags: angular, angular5

G'day people,

So I am using ng2-Simple-timer with my angular 5 app. I'm not sure on how to go about recording time with angular 5 so I just chose ng2-Simple-Timer. I am trying to record time in milliseconds. There is an example on plunker. If I change the 1 second value to 0.001. I get some weird value. I thought that it was because plunker refreshes every half a second so I tested it on my machine but nah, it still didn't work.

plunker http://embed.plnkr.co/HaTd8q/

npm module 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer#example

basically I just want to be able to record the time in milliseconds every time enter is pressed.

Please Advise.

Comment: The best way to store passed time is to store "new Date()" at the timer start moment and then perform "new Date().getTime() - storedDate.getTime()" when you need to retrieve passed time. You will receive time in ms

Comment: Sorry just to be clear is "new Date()" a javascript method that I can call anywhere? Where doth this method cometh from?

Comment: Yes, refer to the js documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Can you leave an answer so I can select it as a solution. Cheerio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to measure time is to use js Date class. Please refer to the next example:

```
var date = new Date(); // Generate a timestamp when you need to start countdown
... do some calculation ...
console.log(new Date().getTime() - date.getTime()); // When you need, subtract saved date from new one
```

You will receive time in ms.

Answer (score 0):

The ng2-simple-timer is updated and support millisecond now.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer#newtimerhr

newTimerHR

Create High Resolution timer with optional customer delay. Unit in millisecond.

`newTimerHR(name: string, msec: number, delay: number = 0): boolean`

`newTimerHR` will create timer `name` and tick every 'number' of milliseconds. Creating timer with the same name multiple times has no side effect.

`delay`: If set to X, will delay the 1st tick for X milliseconds.

Return `false` if timer `name` exist.

```
this.st.newTimerHR('5ms', 5);
this.st.newTimerHR('5ms', 5, 10);
```